# How to integrate a webcam in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, webcam

I need help to capture a webcam. I am a beginner and this is what i have so far.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="camera" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static WPFMediaKit:MultimediaUtil.VideoInputDevices}}"
   DisplayMemberPath="Name" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="8.514,0,0,11.335"/>

<StackPanel x:Name="camContainer" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  Width="320" Height="200" >
 <WPFMediaKit:VideoCaptureElement Name="video" LoadedBehavior="Play" DesiredPixelHeight="240" DesiredPixelWidth="320" Width="320" Height="240" 
 VideoCaptureDevice="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=videoCapDevices}" FPS="30"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Do you have your webcam's driver and api of it for c#(or .net)

Answer (score 0):

you dont seem to have an element named "videoCapDevices"

which means that you are trying to set the device to null.

Assuming you have a SelectedItem on your viewmodel, then the following small change may work ( untested from this end )

```
<ComboBox x:Name="camera" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static WPFMediaKit:MultimediaUtil.VideoInputDevices}}"
   DisplayMemberPath="Name" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" Margin="8.514,0,0,11.335"/>

<StackPanel x:Name="camContainer" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  Width="320" Height="200" >
 <WPFMediaKit:VideoCaptureElement Name="video" LoadedBehavior="Play" DesiredPixelHeight="240" DesiredPixelWidth="320" Width="320" Height="240" 
 VideoCaptureDevice="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}" FPS="30"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: WPF Media Kit is a dead project.